# How to make sure all uploaded files are readable by the webserver?

Tags: permissions, sftp, centos8

Every file uploaded has the wrong permissions so my webserver (Nginx) can't read them. When I manually adjust them by running `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/*` it works again but I'd have to to it everytime I upload a new file. How can I automatically set all permissions of files uploaded via SFTP to 755?

I also tried adding this line to sshd_config:

```
Subsystem    sftp    internal-sftp   -u 0022
```

Comment: Look into ACLs. You can give nginx an ACL on the `/var/www` directory, or better yet, a specific subfolder intended for user uploads, so a hole in your upload script can't overwrite your site's code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,
it's a bad idea to have files executable, so a better solution should be to do folders 755 and files 644 (or 640)

```
find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Now, to ensure files are uploaded with specific permissions, checkout `umask`

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-3814/userconcept-95347/index.html

---

Change the /etc/ssh/sshd_config like this:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -u 0022
```

And if you have a group:

```
Match Group xyz
  .
  .
  .
  ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0022
```

Comment: I know about umask but where to apply it?

Comment: Try in `/etc/login.defs`, although it can be overwritten in a service startup script like `/etc/init.d/ssh` or `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service`

Comment: What is `{} \;` for?

Comment: that is how you need to execute an `-exec` with `find`, `{}` is the name of each file` `\;` is how the line is treated.

Comment: Yes,  `Subsystem sftp /bin/sh -c ‘umask <umask>; /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server’` or `Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -u <umask>`